# Calculate the great common factor between $2^{2n+1}-1$ and $2^{4m+2}+1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-number-theory

How to calculate the great common factor between $2^{2n+1}-1$ and $2^{4m+2}+1$, where $n$ and  $m$ are positive numbers.

**We guess that:**  the great common factor is $1$.

Comment: This question is from studying the order of  the finite non-abelian simple group $^2B_2(q)$

Comment: If that is the context, maybe you should say something about it in your question. Questions of the form "Prove that ...." just sound like homework questions.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $p$ is a prime number that divides $2^{2n+1}-1$.  This means that $2^{2n+1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.  Consequently, the order of $2$ modulo $p$ must be an odd number dividing $2n+1$.

On the other hand, if $q$ is a prime number that divides $2^{4m+2}+1$, then this means $2^{4m+2}\equiv -1\pmod{q}$.  Hence $2^{8m+4}\equiv 1\pmod{q}$.  Thus, the order of $2$ modulo $q$ must be of the form $4k$ for some $k\mid (2m+1)$.

Thus, your two numbers cannot share any prime divisors.

Answer (score 2):

In general we have
$$\gcd(2^a + 1, 2^b - 1) = \frac{2^{\gcd(2a,b)}-1}{2^{\gcd(a,b)}-1},$$
which is evaluates to $1$ for $a=4m+2$ and $b=2n+1$.